# Adicionando Linha de tabela com javascript não funciona evento onchance dos buttons

Tags: javascript

Bom dia, estou adicionando linhas de uma tabela (tblformacao) utilizando javascript e nesta linha eu adiciono um input e estou escutando o evento onchange (.upload), contudo não cai no método. Quando eu troco para onclick funciona. Alguém sabe me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

```js
$('#tblformacao').append('<tr><td>' + option.Text + '</td>' +
                        '' +
                         ' <td>Não</td> ' +
                      '<td> <button class="btn-delete ui-state-default ui-corner-all"      onclick="deletelinha(this)"> ' +
                    ' <span class="icon-remove-sign" /></button> ' +
                       '<input type="file" class="upload" /> ' +
                       ' </td>' +
                         ' <td></td> ' +
                          ' <td></td> ' +
                        '<td style="display:none;">' + $("#CargoId").val() + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>'
);

 $(".upload").on('change', function (e) {
   
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zica, quando você utiliza `$(".upload").change(function () { ... })` ou `$(".upload").on("change", function () { ... })`, ele aplica o evento apenas nos elementos já existes na pagina.

para que estes `EventListener` também sejam aplicados aos elementos insidos dinamicamente, você tem chamar o `$(".upload").on("change", function () { ... })` após adicionar novos elementos, ou usar fazer o seguinte (recomendado):

```
$('#tblformacao').on("change", ".upload", function () { ... });
```

isto vai fazer que todos os elementos com o seletor ".upload" que estejam dentro de `#tblformacao` tenha o `EventListener` `change` associados a eles na sua criação.

Answer (score 1):

Tente:

```
$('table').on('change', '.upload', function(e){
   ...
});
```

Onde table refere-se ao elemento pai.